# Why is the MKS unit of time the same as the CGS unit?

Tags: time, conventions, si-units, metrology

There are many system of units used in physics. In the CGS, the units are,

- length : centimetre
- mass : gram
- time : second

And in the MKS system the units are,

- length : metre
- mass : kilogram
- time : second

Though other units change in different systems, but time's unit never changes. Why?

Comment: I don't think this can be answered (but I may be wrong). Time has always been special with regard to larger intervals than seconds (no kiloseconds etc.).

Comment: This is not a physics question. The choice of units is just arbitrary. You can create a $MKM$ system if you want to..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it belongs to https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is a mistake to think Giorgi's choice was just arbitrary, and not a physics question. On the other hand, the question may belong to HSM.

Comment: Making inferences off a sample of size 2 can be dangerous. Just take a gander at the [Wikipedia entry on 'natural units'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units) and see that the time units are not necessarily seconds.

Comment: You might rephrase your question to something like "When Giorgi proposed replacing the CGS system, he changed the unit of mass from gram to kilogram. Would changing the unit of time have been an alternative option, with the same advantages?". That might be more specific for stackexchange users who seem to think that Giorgi made an arbitrary choice.

Comment: Meta discussion regarding this question: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10982

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of the CGS system was that the base units of CGS were not coherent with the practical electrical units ampere and volt. In CGS, the unit of energy is the erg (1 erg = 1 g cm<sup>2</sup>/s<sup>2</sup>), whereas the electrical units volt and ampere result in 1 joule = 1 V A s = 10<sup>7</sup> erg. The joule was introduced in 1889. Although the joule is called a derived unit in SI, historically MKS and SI are derived from the joule.

Giorgi noticed that a small change in the prefixes of the base units of CGS could achieve coherence with the joule. His new base units were decimal (sub)multiples of the old base units, and only one of the base units had a prefix, similar to CGS. So the unit of length lost its prefix, $cm \rightarrow m$, while either the unit of mass or the unit of time obtained a prefix.
Giorgi's solution was to change the unit of mass:  $ {joule} = [M]\ m^2\ s^{-2}  \rightarrow  [M] = 1\ {kg}$

Trying to change the unit of time did not result in a decimal (sub)multiple of the second: $ {joule} = g\ m^2\ [t]^{-2}  \rightarrow  [t] = 10^{-1.5}\ second$